# Sending a SelectList Selection to a Create View from a Layout Modal MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a small view inside of an HTML.Action that lives inside my _Layout. I am trying to send the ProjectId of the selected project to the Create Ticket View. My modal view looks like this.

Here is the controller method for the modal view:

```
        [AllowAnonymous] // Change this to only submitters
        public ActionResult NavRoleItems()
        {
            ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(db.Projects, "Id", "Name");

            return View();
        }
```

**Modal View**

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Tickets", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.ProjectId, null, new { @class = "form-control"})
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Issue" />
                </div>
            }
```

And I want to send any way I can really, but Ideally I want to send it as the projId variable below. Im in school and this is the first time I have played with Formmethod.Get.

**Controller View**

```
        public ActionResult Create(string projId)
        {
            TicketCreateViewModel model = new TicketCreateViewModel();

            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var user = db.Users.Find(userId);
            model.OwnerUserId = userId;
            model.OwnerUser = user;
            model.ProjectId = projId;
            model.AssignedToUserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "FirstName");
            ViewBag.TicketPriorityId = new SelectList(db.TicketPriorities, "Id", "Name");
            ViewBag.TicketStatusId = new SelectList(db.TicketStatuses, "Id", "Name");
            ViewBag.TicketTypeId = new SelectList(db.TicketTypes, "Id", "Name");
            return View();
        }
```

Every way that I have tried it, html hidden and as a param in the begin form, doesn't work because it sees the @Model.ProjectId as null when it loads. As it should bc it is null. But how can I tell it to send it to the Create Tickets controller after the user selects and hits submit?

Comment: can you please share your calling method for view

Comment: Yes, I will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Change This in your view**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectId, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProjectId , "Value", "Text"), "...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Change your controller variable name by ProjectId 
It might Work fine

**Another Way**

**You can add onclick in your button**

```
function submitForm()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'Url',
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({projId: $('ProjectId').val()}),
        success: function(objStatus) {},
        error: function(xhr, status, error)
        {
            if(status === "timeout")
            {
                alert(msg_timeout);
            }
            else
            {
                alert(msg_error);
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: first for all you have to fill your list that done by first way and then it up to you u can make submit call or ajax call

Comment: I actually had to keep that second param null, but when I changed my controller param name as you suggested it all worked!!!!

Answer (score 0):

why you set null the feeder argument of dropDownListFor ?

set with ViewBag.ProjectId content instead of null

Or

you can fill the viewbag with projects data and in view
do like this :

**Controller**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult NavRoleItems()
{
    ViewBag.Projects = db.Projects;

    return View();
 }
```

**View**

add a model top of the page that it has ProjectId property

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProjectId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Projects, "Id", "Name"))
```

change Create action argument to type that insert top of the view

Comment: I dont understand the feeder arg, it is my third week of school

Comment: the second argument of dropdownlistfor is for fill the DropDown , set it with your data